# Sharepoint Calculated Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have one requirement where I need to populate the column with today's date and with number of document submitted today for ex: 20161231-01 this indicates for today's date there is one document already submitted, so if I want to upload new document then it show me 20161231-02

Can anyone assist me fixing this.

Regards
Anand

Comment: Which tools can you use? SharePoint Designer, Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with a calculated column. The calculated column can get values of other field of your current item only.
To do that, you can use Workflow (with SharePoint Designer or VisualStudio), or TimerJob (with dev), or custom form (with code behind), or Event Receiver (with dev).